# Add files to Centos Live CD

Tags: centos, squashfs

I'm trying to 'inject' 2 files into a Centos 6 live CD ISO. 
Process to date:

1. extracted the files from the iso to `./files/`
2. extracted the files from the squashfs.img to `./squashfs/`
3. mounted the extfs3.img
4. copied the 2 files to the mountpoint `/LiveOS/`
5. unmounted the extfs3.img
6. created the squashfs.img `#mksquashfs ./LiveOS ./squashfs.img`
7. copied the squashfs.img to its location
   under `./files/LiveOS`
8. run `mkisofs` to create the ISO

Every time I boot the server from the modified ISO, it gets through the post/isolinux process, but then hangs at a kernel panic.